# Ansible - colorized output in Azure DevOps

Tags: azure, ansible

When running Ansible on Azure DevOps, the output is not colorized but everything is simply shown in black/white.
Even when setting `ansible_force_color` to true in the ansible.cfg it's black/white.

As a last resort, we could 'echo' the [colorized output logging command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/scripts/logging-commands?view=azure-devops&tabs=bash#formatting-commands) to Azure.  In this case, the output would be colorized.

Is there a (good) way to hook these logging output commands to Ansible just before a task has been executed?
E.g. if a task was OK, it should be colored as green, thus `##[section]` is echo'ed before printing the task.

Answer (score 1):

So, i just figured it out.
In the Azure task, i've defined:

```yaml
env:
  ANSIBLE_FORCE_COLOR: "1"
```

And now it shows colorized output.

Comment: Also works in GitLab + Ansible, except that global variables are defined by `variables` and not `env`.

Comment: Where do you set this in Azure DevOps? I can't seem to find where to define it in the GUI pipelines.

Comment: we don't use gui's.